# System.InvalidCastException: 'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, sqlclient

I migrated my project from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 3.0. Now I get this exception. In ASP.NET Core 2.2 it was using `FromSql()`; now it is using `FromSqlRaw()`. I am calling my procedure using Entity Framework Core.

```
SqlParameter Username = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "USERNAME",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Value = user.Username,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Size = 50
            };

SqlParameter Password = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "PASSWORD",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Value = user.Password,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Size = 50
            };

SqlParameter msgOut = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "MSG",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                Size = 1000
            };

SqlParameter statusOut = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "STATUS",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };

var sql = @"EXEC PRC_USERS_LOGIN
                        @USERNAME, 
                        @PASSWORD, 
                        @MSG OUT, 
                        @STATUS OUT";

Users resultUser = new Users();
resultUser = ctx.Users.FromSqlRaw(sql, Username, Password, msgOut, statusOut)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This code worked after replacing

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
```

to

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
```

and

```
FirstOrDefault();
```

to

```
ToList();
```

Comment: The first portion of you answer here is actually what fixes your issue not the `FirstOrDefault();` to `ToList();`.

Answer (score 28):

Fixed by changing using System.Data.SqlClient to using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16812#issuecomment-516013245

Comment: Yes that was also the problem. Thanks,

Comment: Meanwhile I'm getting error when I'm using 'Microfoft.Data.SqlClient' namespace. but 'Sytem.Data.SqlClient' can pass null column without any error message. This is my code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499253/the-sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not)

Answer (score -1):

The reverse is true also: you must use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameters` with EF 6, *not* `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameters`.

Also be sure to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecords`, not `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server.SqlDataRecords`.