# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to use one of these namespaces

```
//using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

My model

```
public class Get_Data_Scholar{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ID_Transcript { get; set; }
    public string Year_Semester { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
        public JsonResult Get_GPA_Tuition (Int32 id)
        {
            var ID_NCS = new SqlParameter("@ID_NCS", id);
            List<Get_data> get_Data = new List<Models.Get_Data_Scholar>();
            get_Data = _applicationDbContext.Get_Data_Scholar.FromSql(
                            "EXEC [dbo].[Get_Data_Scholar]  @ID"

                            , id
                            ).ToList();

            return Json(get_Data );
        }
```

When I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient`, everything works well. But when I change different namespace to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, it produce error message like this:

> System.InvalidCastException   HResult=0x80004002   **Message=The
>   SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type
>   objects, not SqlParameter objects.**   Source=System.Data.SqlClient
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object
>   value)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(Object
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.DynamicRelationalParameter.AddDbParameter(DbCommand
>   command, Object value)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.CompositeRelationalParameter.AddDbParameter(DbCommand
>   command, Object value)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalParameterBase.AddDbParameter(DbCommand
>   command, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.CreateCommand(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean
>   buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1
>   enumerable)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)

When I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient`, return query from SQL server with `null` value can be bypass without any error message.
But when it changes to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, return query from SQL Server must be treated with special treatment. So, How do I do/overcome this error message ?
I knew this question kind of [old style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705767/sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not-str) but how to treat `non-null SqlParameter`because of some return `null` column ?

The reason I'm trying to change `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace because near in the future some sensitive column will be encrypted using AKV ([AlwaysEncrypted](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault)).

Comment: You could check if your parameter is null and based on that you can handle your situation accordingly: `if(ID_NCS  != null){ // your logic} else {//handle null condition}`

Comment: ID_NCS never be null because it's a feed parameter. What will be null is the return query from SQL Server after execute Store procedure.

Comment: Which version of .NET CORE are you on?

Comment: it's .NET CORE v 2.2

Comment: Well, I believe that you should upgrade to .NET CORE 3.0. Read this article for more information: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/12/19/net-core-life_0.aspx and https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16812

Comment: well, it gonna be a long night this weekend.

Comment: Hahaha, well you gotta do what you gotta do. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you're saying that when the value of your sql param is the literal null, this blows up, and you do not want this to happen. You need to detect null and instead use System.DBNull.Value.

Comment: thank for your curious my question, how to detect return null value by using SystemDBNull.Value ?

Comment: `new SqlParameter("@ID_NCS", id == null ? DBNull.Value : id)` although in your example id is a non-nullable int, so I see now that my answer is fairly irrelevant ><

Answer (score -1):

You can try like change to `FromSqlRaw` and also change `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter`

```
 get_Data = _applicationDbContext.Get_Data_Scholar.FromSql(
                        "EXEC [dbo].[Get_Data_Scholar] {0}", 
                         id).ToList();
```

Comment: what kind of assembly should I use ?  Error message: dbset <Get_Data_Scholar> does not contain a definition for 'FromSqlRaw' and no accessible extension methot 'FromSqlRaw' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<Get_Data_Scholar>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, it's already installed. Or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient only works on .Net Core v.3 ?

Comment: try adding using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; at the top of namespaces

Comment: By adding this namespace Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter, using directive is unnecessary.